# Migrating to Android Studio: how to better configure logcat view

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm migrating from eclipse to Android Studio. I'm having a hard time on some basic issues, one of them being inspecting the log efficiently.

In eclipse, I usually inspected the logcat output maximizing the LogCat tab (double click on the tab to maximize, and again to minimize). This is fast and can be done from either the DDMS, Java or Debug perspectives.
In Android Studio, there seems to be only one perspective, and the DDMS frame is pinned to the left bottom corner. To maximize, the only way I've found by now is to put the window into float mode (using that gear icon in the DDMS window corner) and then resize it. To minimize it again I've to click the gear icon again and disable the float mode.

This is too much work compared to eclipse. Is there a better way?

Also in the logcat window, in eclipse all the columns (Time, PID, TID, Application, Tag, Text) were displayed and resizable. However in Android Studio I can't see the column names, so I don't know what is being displayed, and there's no way to resize the columns. Is there any way of configuring the columns? All I've found in settings was the options to change the line colours according to the debug level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I see you can solve the maximizing and minimizing problem, is to resize the Android DDMS window (and consequently logcat window) to the size you desire (by clicking on the top of the Android DDMS window and dragging up/down until you reach the size of the Android DDMS window you desire) and then use "6:Android" button at the bottom left area of the screen to show and hide the window respectively.

Example:
[image]

(use this button to show/hide the Window DDMS window)

[image]

As for the columns problem, I don't think there is currently a way to show the columns, for now you just need to use the logcat this way, there may be some updates in the future regarding this issue.